# SQL count by group concatenations

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have data formatted like this:

```
id   item
1      a
1      b
1      c
2      a
2      b
3      x
3      y
3      z
4      a
4      b
4      c
```

Is there any way to dynamically build a list of all the combinations of "items" for a given id and count them?  The output would look like this:

```
combo count
abc    2
ab     1
xyz    1
```

This is something I could do in Excel pretty easily but I wasn't sure if there was a way to automate it in SQL.

Comment: Those are not combinations that you are listing, they are merely simple concatenations.

Comment: You're right.  I'm not sure how to structure the concatenation across the ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by concatenating the values together for each `id`.  This is yucky in SQL Server, because it doesn't support a `group_concat()` or `listagg()` or similar function.  You can do it with a correlated subquery.

Then, just count the combos:

```
select combo, count(*)
from (select (select item
              from table t2
              where t2.id = t.id
              order by item
              for xml path ('')
             ) as combo
      from table t
      group by id
     ) c
group by combo;
```

Comment: Thanks, I just realized it was a concatenation problem, this should get the job done, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
declare @t table (id int, item char(1))

insert into @t select '1',      'a'
insert into @t select '1',      'b'
insert into @t select '1',      'c'
insert into @t select '2',      'a'
insert into @t select '2',      'b'
insert into @t select '3',      'x'
insert into @t select '3',      'y'
insert into @t select '3',      'z'
insert into @t select '4',      'a'
insert into @t select '4',      'b'
insert into @t select '4',      'c'

;with d as (
  select distinct id from @t
),
groups as (
  select
    id, 
    name = (select item from @t t where d.id = t.id for xml path(''))
  from d
)
select name, [count] = count(*) 
from groups g
group by name
order by 2 desc
```